# Get Type of Entities in HashMap Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, hashmap

I am trying to get the type of the key and value of a `HashMap` using reflection. I have the following code:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", 1);
    Class c = map.getClass();
    if (c.getTypeParameters().length > 0) {
        Type superClass = c.getGenericSuperclass();
        TypeVariable<?> f = (TypeVariable<?>)(((ParameterizedType)superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        for (Type type1 : ((ParameterizedType)superClass).getActualTypeArguments()) {
            TypeVariable<?> c1 = (TypeVariable<?>)type1;
            System.out.println(c1.getBounds()[0]);
        }
    }
```

But this prints:

```
class java.lang.Object
class java.lang.Object
```

Instead of:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
```

I assume I'm doing something stupid. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you're not. Read about type erasure.

Comment: It will work if you do `new HashMap<String, Integer>() { }`. Read about "super type tokens" to learn why.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux is correct, you cannot get the types of the `HashMap`. What I ended up doing was looking at the `Class` of the key and value of an entry in the map. This does require an instance of the map instead of just the class but it works for me. Can I close this question or is it closed because it's marked as a duplicate?